# Firefox has odd gears icon pane on the right hand side

Tags: firefox, browser

Somehow, I have a user profile on the same machine I'm using now where Firefox has a pane on the right with a gears icon:

[image: gears icon]

How do I remove this pane?  I tried `Customize...` but wasn't able to remove it.  Bonus points for speculating on what I did, PEBKAC, to cause this oddity.

Comment: You should add the versions of Ubuntu and Firefox to your question.